# Bayesian Inference: decision making and nested probabilism

Tags: probability-theory, statistical-inference, bayesian

*Disclaimer: I struggle quite a bit with statistics, let me know if something is difficult to understand.*

I have two populations $A$ and $B$ with binary values ($1$ represents "success", $0$ "failure") and sizes $N_A$, and $N_B$. My goal is to determine which population has the higher absolute number of successes.

The random variable which determines the number of successes in a sample of $n_i$ observations is $X_i \sim Hyp(N_i, K_i, n_i)$ with unknown number of successes $K_i, i\in\{A,B\}$ . Unfortunately, $K_i$ can assume any value, including $N_i$ and $0$.

From what I understood, this can be solved well with Bayesian Inference. I use the betabinomial distribution as conjugate prior with $\alpha=\beta=0.5$, and thereby determine the two posterior distributions. Finally, I subtract the posteriors from each other using convolution:  $h_{Z}(K_B - K_A| x_A, x_B)$ .

---

Question 1: How do I interpret the outcome? My best guess would be to determine $H(p)=\int_{-\infty}^p h_Z(z)dz$. Then I would choose $A$ as having more succeeding members than $B$ if $H_z(0)<0.5$. For $H_z(0) > 0.5$, $B$ seems to have more succeeding members. Is it correct, that the result of $H_z(0)$ will also give me the probability that this decision is correct?

Is there a better way to approach this? I have read about cost functions for decisions, but I have a hard time quantifying the cost of a false decision.

---

Question 2: I would like to include a second layer of probabilism into the model.
The members of $A$ and $B$ can only be determined as "success" and "failure" (or 1 and 0) with $P(\text{"success"} | \text{"failure"}) > 0$ (and $P(\text{"failure"} | \text{"success"}) = 0$).
How can I incorporate this into the interpretation of my Bayesian Inference results? Since the two models are not independent, I am not sure how to handle this. Is the right way here simulation?

For context: To determine "success" and "failure", I use sampling to check whether all items in (another) population have a value of 1.

Comment: How large are $N_A,N_B$? Are they significantly larger than your sample sizes $n_A,n_B$? If so, and if you observe at least ten successes and at least ten failures in each sample, you may find it more convenient to perform a one$-$tailed hypothesis test with null hypothesis $$H_0:p_AN_A=p_BN_B$$ where $p_A,p_B$ are the true proportion of successes in each population. The conditions I outlined above will allow you to use normal approximations to estimate the sampling distributions of $\hat{P}_A,\hat{P}_B$

Comment: @Matthew: unfortunately it is possible that all observations are 0 or all observations are 1.  $n_i$  should be much smaller than $N_i$ though.

Comment: The non zero possibility of observing a sample with all successes or all failures doesn't prevent you from using normal approximations. Here is the rule. Suppose you sample $n$ individuals from a population without replacement that has $K$ successes and $N-K$ failures. Let $X$ denote the number of successes belonging to your sample. If $\frac{n}{N}$ is less than $0.05$ you can approximate $X$ with a $\text{Binomial}\Big(n,\frac{K}{N}\Big)$ random variable. This is called the 5% rule.

Comment: Moreover, if $\frac{nK}{N}$ and $n\Big(1-\frac{K}{N}\Big)$ are both at least $10$, you can approximate $X$ with a normal random variable with mean $\mu=\frac{nK}{N}$ and standard deviation $\sigma=\sqrt{n\cdot \frac{K}{N}\cdot \Big(1-\frac{K}{N}\Big)}$ The condition of having at least $10$ expected successes/failures in your sample is often called the "normal condition." There are other variations of these rules out there, but these are the rules I refer to the most.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Oh, I actually confused the CLT with the "normal condition" in my post. The problem is, that $K_i$ can be $0$ and it can be $N_i$. Regarding the 5% rule for Binomial approximation, I've read that $p$ cannot be close to $0$ or $1$ [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Related_distributions). Is the 5% rule circumventing this? I am unsure whether having these edge cases even matters so much in my use case. I assume the issue is that the resulting distribution would allocate a positive probability to impossible outcomes?

Comment: Also, would using frequentist statistics help me beyond the ability to use classic Hypothesis tests?

Comment: If $K_i\approx 0,N_i$ then $p=\frac{K_i}{N_i} \approx 0,1$ rendering the expected number of successes $np$ or failures $n(1-p)$ to be too small. This would violate the normal condition. When $np$ or $n(1-p)$ are too small the "balance point" of the probability histogram for the binomial distribution would be close to one of its truncated boundaries at $0$ or $n$ making its shaped skewed right or skewed left, respectively. If you use normal approximation the shape of the histogram should be "bell shaped". There is no problem approximation hypergeometric probabilities with binomial ones, however

Comment: I see, that makes sense. So your idea is to suggest using Binomial approximation to use Hypothesis in response to question 1, right? Or is there a way to use this for question 2, too?